# Get the part of string after the delimiter

Tags: bash, shell, parsing

The string format is

```
Executed: variable_name
```

What is the simplest way to get the *variable_name* sub-string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foo="Executed: variable_name"
echo ${foo##* }     # Strip everything up to and including the rightmost space.
```

or

```
set -- $foo
echo $2
```

Unlike other solutions using awk, sed, and whatnot, these don't fork other programs and save thousands of CPU cycles since they execute completely in your shell. They are also more portable (unlike `${i/* /}` which is a bashism).

Answer (score 0):

With [sed](/questions/tagged/sed):

```
echo "Executed: variable_name" | sed 's/[^:]*: //'
```

Answer (score 0):

Using awk:

```
echo 'Executed: variable_name' | awk -F' *: *' '{print $2}'
variable_name
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the string in a variable:

```
$ i="Executed: variable_name"
$ echo ${i/* /}
variable_name
```

If you have the string as output of a command

```
$ cmd
Executed: variable_name
$ cmd | awk '{print $NF}'
variable_name
```

Note that 'NF' means "number of fields", so $NF is always the last field on the line. Fields are assumed to be separated by spaces (unless -F is specified)
If your variable_name could have spaces in it, the

`-F' *: *'`

mentioned previously ensures that only the ": " is used as a field separator.  However, this will preserve spaces at the end of the line if there are any.

If the line is mixed in with other output, you might need to filter.

Either grep..

```
$ cmd | grep '^Executed: ' | awk '{print $NF}'
```

or more clever awk..

```
$ cmd | awk '/^Executed: /{print $NF}'
```